# How Feasible is integrating ROS with a CAN Bus?

Tags: ros, can

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am pretty new to ROS, but I am have troubles finding any useful info about the CAN Bus and ROS. Could someone point me in the right direction?

I would love to use a Raspberry Pi and a PiCAN to interact with my already existing J1939 CAN Bus network. I have it working for monitoring and such with a custom setup at the moment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246507/how-feasible-is-integrating-ros-with-a-can-bus?/) by [radix07](https://answers.ros.org/users/28350/radix07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-26**:
I'm not a CAN expert, but there are some packages targeting CAN, [ros_canopen](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_canopen) being one of them. Whether you can use that specific pkg I can't say, as it depends on what you are doing exactly and what you're constraints are.

**Comment by [radix07](https://answers.ros.org/users/28350/radix07/) on 2016-10-26**:
Interesting that there is at least something out there. I don't need CAN Open and would be fine with just some frame level access. Perhaps just pulling out the Socket CAN Bridge/Interfaces could be useful for other CAN protocols as well... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No ROS integration (yet), but [gitlab.com/lely_industries/can](https://gitlab.com/lely_industries/can) could also be interesting. It's event-based nature should make it relatively straightforward to map it into ROS.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1